# Access voice attributes in Mac OS NSSpeechSynthesizer library

Tags: swift

I'm stumped as to how to access voice attributes. I know this is probably a newbie question and it's soimething very basic in Swift, but I can't figure it out for the life of me. According to this site,
https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/nsspeechsynthesizer/1448458-attributes
I can access voice attributes by accessing the dictioanry. I have found a list of attributes called name, age, gender, etc.
However, when I call attributes for a given voice identifier I get a bunch of strange value and I am unable to access anything:
My latest attempt was to do this, but it did not work:

```
struct ttsVoice {
    let name: String
    let language: String
}

let tts = NSSpeechSynthesizer()
let availableVoices = NSSpeechSynthesizer.availableVoices
let voiceMap: [ttsVoice]=[]
func listVoices() -> Void {
    availableVoices.forEach { element in
        let voiceDictionary = NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributes(forVoice: element)
let name = voiceDictionary["name"]

}
    }
```

I have tried many other approaches, some said that I can't convert string to NSVoiceAttributeKey, etc. This one just says Cannot convert value of type 'String' to expected argument type 'NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceAttributeKey', engine.swift, Error

Has anyone done this before? I'm sure it's something quite simple.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I figured it out. It was very counterintuitive. Appparently this dictionary has voiceATtributeKeys as keys, not strings. So you need to do like:

```
    availableVoices.forEach { element in
        let voiceDictionary = NSSpeechSynthesizer.attributes(forVoice: element)
        let name = voiceDictionary[NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceAttributeKey.name]!
        let language = voiceDictionary[NSSpeechSynthesizer.VoiceAttributeKey.localeIdentifier]!
print("voice \(name) speaks \(language)")
}
```

Thanks